# FlutterでScaffoldが最下層のままDefaultTabControllerを利用したい

Tags: flutter

FlutterのScaffoldとDefaultTabControllerに関する質問となります。

現在Flutterを学習しており、DefaultTabControllerを触っています。
「Scaffoldはウィジェットツリーの最下層に来るもの」と習い、以下のコードのようにScaffoldのbodyにDefaultTabControllerを配置する形で使おうとしましたが、実行するとTabBarとTabBarViewが表示されません。TabBarとTabBarViewはColumn内に配置したいと考えております。

様々なサイトのDefaultTabControllerのサンプルコードを見ると、DefaultTabControllerが最下層に来てそのchildにscaffold、scaffoldのappBarにTabBar、bodyにTabBarViewを配置しているものばかりなのですが、必ずそのような形でないとDefaultTabControllerは使えないのでしょうか？
将来的に作るアプリは、ScaffoldのappBarは表示しないようにしたと思っています。

Scaffoldを最下層に置き、その上にDefaultTabControllerを配置するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.limeAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Welcome to Flutter!!!')), // 将来的にappBarはなくしたい
        body: DefaultTabController( // DefaultTabControllerはScafoldのbodyに配置したい
          length: 2,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TabBar( // TabBarが表示されない
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'タブ1'),
                  Tab(text: 'タブ2')
                ]
              ),
              TabBarView( // TabBarViewも表示されない
                children: [
                  Text('ページ1'),
                  Text('ページ2')
                ]
              )
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

原因は「DefaultTabControllerがScaffoldより上層に来ていること」ではなく、「TabBarViewがExpandedウィジェット内に配置されていなかったこと」のようでした（おそらくそれが根本原因ではないと思いますが）。

以下のコードでやりたいことができました。お騒がせいたしました。

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.limeAccent,
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'タブ1'),
                  Tab(text: 'タブ2')
                ]
              ),
              Expanded( // Expandedが必要だった
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    Text('ページ1'),
                    Text('ページ2')
                  ]
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```